# copying files from folder and embedding it in powerpoint slide

Tags: vba

In a folder there are some files which I want to copy and embed it in my powerpoint slide.
I have written a code, however it is giving error "Run Time Error . Shapes unknown member: Invalid Request on this line:

> `Set obchart = pres.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 200, 100, folderpath & fil.Name, True)`

```
Sub copyfilestoppt()
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fil As Scripting.file
    Dim foldername As Scripting.Folder
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim pres As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim obchart As Object

    folderpath = "C:\Users\av\Desktop\Macro\Excel maacro"
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set foldername = fso.GetFolder(folderpath)
    Set pres = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    'loop
    For Each fil In foldername.Files
        With ActivePresentation
            Set pres = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
            Set obchart = pres.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 200, 100, folderpath & fil.name, True)
        End With
    Next fil
    Set obchart = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So it is excel Files. You want to copy the whole file or just a range ?

Comment: Yes in my folder there are 5 excel file which I want to embed in a powerpoint slide

Comment: Actually I want all these excel files should be attached as an attachment in my powerpoint slide

Comment: `folderpath & fil.name` -----> `folderpath & "\" & fil.name`

Comment: I tried this it still gives me error Run time error, shapes unknown member := Invalid request on this line

Comment: Set obchart = pres.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 200, 100, folderpath & "\" & fil.Name, True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the "\" between the path and the file name, and you misplaced the arguments. Try this:

```
Set obchart = pres.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 200, 100, , folderpath & "\" & fil.Name, True)
'                                                         ^^^           ^^^^^^
```